# How to insert an element at a specific position of an empty vector?

Tags: vector, append, julia

In R we can create an empty vector where it is possible to insert an element in any position of this vector.
Example:

```
> x <- c()
> x[1] = 10
> x[4] = 20
```

The final result is:

```
> x
[1] 10 NA NA 20
```

I would like to do something similar using Julia, but couldn't find a way to do this.
The “append” function do not perform something like that.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps:

1. First resize the vector or create a vector with an appropriate size.
2. Next set the elements accordingly.

Since you are coming from R I assume you want the vector to be initially filled with missing values. Here is the way to do this.

In my example I assume you want to store integers in the vector. Before both options load the Missings.jl package:

```
using Missings
```

#### Option 1. Start with an empty vector

```
julia> x = missings(Int, 0)
Union{Missing, Int64}[]

julia> resize!(x, 4)
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 missing
 missing
 missing
 missing

julia> x[1] = 10
10

julia> x[4] = 40
40

julia> x
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 10
   missing
   missing
 40
```

#### Option 2. Preallocate a vector

```
julia> x = missings(Int, 4)
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 missing
 missing
 missing
 missing

julia> x[1] = 10
10

julia> x[4] = 40
40
```

---

The reason why Julia does not resize the vectors automatically is for safety. Sometimes it would be useful, but most of the time if `x` is an empty vector and you write `x[4] = 40` it is a bug in the code and Julia catches such cases.

---

#### EDIT

What you can do is:

```
function setvalue(vec::Vector, idx, val)
    @assert idx > 0
    if idx > length(vec)
        resize!(vec, idx)
    end
    vec[idx] = val
    return vec
end
```

Comment: Or, without using sny package,  `Vrctor{Union{Missing,Int64}}(missing,4)`

Comment: Agreed, but I thought @Douglas would find it verbose :).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers @BogumiłKamiński ! My problem is that I would like to avoid having to initially specify the vector size or having to resize the vector size multiple times. The fact that R automatically resizes vectors makes it a lot easier because I sometimes have loops where I don't know the size of the vector initially, and the size of the vector increases until its value reaches a certain limit.

Comment: If you really need it I have written a simple function that does what you want. As said - in Julia such thing is not done by default as it is unsafe.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks @BogumiłKamiński !